# Issue editing nginx.conf using Docker and NGINX

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm having trouble figuring out how to edit `nginx.conf` inside NGINX open source Docker container.

I'm trying to follow the directions here:

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/installing-nginx/installing-nginx-docker/#maintaining-content-and-configuration-files-in-the-container

I've gotten through all 4 steps succcessfully. I have SSH access using the helper `mynginx4_files` container.

This part confuses me, though:

> - the /bin/bash argument means that the bash shell runs in the helper
>     container, presenting a shell prompt that you can use to modify files
>     as needed

This sounds good! I do have the bash prompt now, but unfortunately, I don't see any way I can modify nginx.conf. There's no text editor that I can see. I don't see vi or emacs or anything else. (I searched through all 4 'bin' directories, and `whereis` and `find` didn't turn up anything for `vi`.) I tried to install `vi` using `apt-get` but was unsuccessful. I even tried ubuntu instead of debian, but even with ubuntu there is no text editor. I thought `vi` is standard on all Linux distributions. I don't know what's up, but I feel like I'm missing something big here. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to edit `nginx.conf` in the container, you can just create a new `nginx.conf` on the host, modify it, and use `-v` to map it to the container.

Something like:

```
docker run --name my-custom-nginx-container -v /host/path/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro -d nginx
```

Maybe also have a look at [nginx on docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx)

Comment: This works. NGINX docs are pretty overcomplicated. A little peeved that I couldn't use 'vi' and still wondering why there's no text editor. But this mounting/mapping did work for me.

Comment: This based on the base image of your used image, to make image smaller, most of image will drop unnecessary things, here is vi. But you really can install it for yourself. If debian, you still use apt install or centos still use yum. You did not tell why you apt operation fail and the error log, so we don't know what happened, but it really can.